# How to send Json from client with missing fields for its corresponding Case Class after using Json.format function

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have a case Class and its companion object like below. Now, when I send JSON without id, createdAt and deletedAt fields, because I set them elsewhere, I get `[NoSuchElementException: JsError.get]` error. It's because I do not set above properties.

How could I achieve this and avoid getting the error?

```
case class Plan(id: String,
                companyId: String,
                name: String,
                status: Boolean = true,
                @EnumAs planType: PlanType.Value,
                brochureId: Option[UUID],
                lifePolicy: Seq[LifePolicy] = Nil,
                createdAt: DateTime,
                updatedAt: DateTime,
                deletedAt: Option[DateTime]
                )

object Plan {
   implicit val planFormat = Json.format[Plan]
   def fromJson(str: JsValue): Plan = Json.fromJson[Plan](str).get
   def toJson(plan: Plan): JsValue = Json.toJson(plan)
   def toJsonSeq(plan: Seq[Plan]): JsValue = Json.toJson(plan)
}
```

JSON I send from client

```
{
    "companyId": "e8c67345-7f59-466d-a958-7c722ad0dcb7",
    "name": "Creating First Plan with enum Content",
    "status": true,
    "planType": "Health",
    "lifePolicy": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce another case class just to handle serialization from request:
like this

```
  case class NewPlan(name: String,
            status: Boolean = true,
            @EnumAs planType: PlanType.Value,
            brochureId: Option[UUID],
            lifePolicy: Seq[LifePolicy] = Nil        
            )
```

and then use this class to populate your Plan class.

Comment: I have several classes like this, so for every class i will have to make a new class. is there any other solution?

Comment: @acjay recommends some other solution, but only this one is clean and solid, others requires some changes to json formatters or making id of you model Optional - you do not want to do this, it may lead to hard to find bugs. Keep your domain model clean.

Comment: @grotrianster Respectfully, I think all of the options have their place. If (supposing) the first thing the code does when it encounters a new plan is create a real `id` for it, and this is the same situation for a whole bunch of models, there are definitely drawbacks to making and maintaining tightly coupled near-clones of every model. On the other hand, if there's a whole bunch of logic specifically for handling data in the `NewPlan` state, then maybe it makes sense to reify the incomplete state as a type in its own right, as you suggest.

Comment: @acjay it's always better to have more solution to the problem, we are not in a position to see full picture here, any solution can be valid :)

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental issue is that by the time a `case class` is instantiated to represent your data, it must be well-typed. To shoe horn your example data into your example class, the types don't match because some fields are missing. It's literally trying to call the constructor without enough arguments.

You've got a couple options:

- You can make a model that represents the incomplete data (as grotrianster suggested).
- You can make the possible missing fields `Option` types.
- You can custom-write the `Reads` part of your `Format` to introduce intelligent values or dummy values for the missing ones.

Option 3 might look something like:

```
// Untested for compilation, might need some corrections

val now: DateTime = ...

val autoId = Reads[JsObject] { 
  case obj: JsObject => JsSuccess(obj \ 'id match {
    case JsString(_) => obj
    case _ => obj.transform(
      __.update((__ \ 'id).json.put("")) andThen
      __.update((__ \ 'createdTime).json.put(now)) andThen
      __.update((__ \ 'updatedTime).json.put(now))
    )
  })
  case _ => JsError("JsObject expected")
}

implicit val planFormat = Format[Plan](
  autoId andThen Json.reads[Plan],
  Json.writes[Plan])
```

Once you do this once, if the issue is the same for all your other models, you can probably abstract it into some `Format` factory utility function.

This may be slightly cleaner for `autoId`:

```
val autoId = Reads[JsObject] {
  // Leave it alone if we have an ID already
  case obj: JsObject if (obj \ 'id).asOpt[String].isSome => JsSuccess(obj)
  // Insert dummy values if we don't have an `id`
  case obj: JsObject => JsSuccess(obj.transform(
    __.update((__ \ 'id).json.put("")) andThen
    __.update((__ \ 'createdTime).json.put(now)) andThen
    __.update((__ \ 'updatedTime).json.put(now))
  ))
  case _ => JsError("JsObject expected")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I tried using Option types and it works but i cannot make them Option.

Comment: @user3918013 Added an example of how you might do it with a custom `Format`