# Request body to case class conversion in play & scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I've a case class similar to this [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788970/using-json-implicit-reader) :

```
case class WebCategory(topGroupName: String,
                       topGroupID: String,
                       webCategoryName : String,
                       webCategoryID : String,
                       subWebCats:Seq[SubWebCat])

case class SubWebCat(name:String, id:String)
```

And my request body json is having the exact same key names as of case class. For ex:

```
{
  "webCategoryID" : "blah",
  "webCategoryName" : "abcabc",
  "topGroupID" : "blah",
  "topGroupName" : "namehere",
  "subWebCats" : [
    {
      "name" : "blah",
      "id" : "idblah"
    },
            {
      "name" : "another blah",
      "id" : "another idblah"
    } 

  ]

}
```

The case class & req body keys are same then is it possible to directly build the case class object from request json? If it is possible then how can I do this? Any references would help. If it is not possible then this means I've to define my custom implicit converter explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788970/using-json-implicit-reader) in which I don't have any problem implementing it.

Note: I'm using Play 2.3 & Scala 11 for my development

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Play's built-in JSON validation for this quite easily.  You don't need to add any third-party dependencies for this.

```
case class WebCategory(topGroupName: String,
                       topGroupID: String,
                       webCategoryName : String,
                       webCategoryID : String,
                       subWebCats:Seq[SubWebCat])

object WebCategory {
  implicit val fmt = Json.format[WebCategory]
}

case class SubWebCat(name:String, id:String)

object SubWebCat {
  implicit val fmt = Json.format[SubWebCat]
}
```

Then, in your controller action:

```
def save: Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>
  request.body.validate[WebCategory].fold(
    errors => BadRequest(errors.mkString),
    category => Ok("saved category")
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We use FasterXml for  serialization and deserialization as follows.

include this dependency in your build.sbt

`"com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.4.0-rc2"`

Create a two helper functions toJson and fromJson to serialize and deserialize

```
 object JsonProvider {
    
      //create mapper and register scala module
      private val mapper = new ObjectMapper
      mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)      
    
      def toJson(obj: Object): String = {
        val writer = new StringWriter
        mapper.writeValue(writer, obj)
        writer.toString
      }
    
      def fromJson[T: scala.reflect.Manifest](json: String): T = {
        mapper.readValue(json, scala.reflect.classTag[T].runtimeClass).asInstanceOf[T]
      }
 }
```

Use it as follows to cast your request body into case class.

```
JsonProvider.fromJson[WebCategory](request.body.toString())
```

to convert caseclass to json use it like this.

```
JsonProvider.toJson(obj);
```

where "obj" is the object of case class.

## Problem with Play-Json default.

Suppose you have case class A with three parameters as follows

```
case class A(id:String,name:String,roll:Int)
```

and if your Json you want to parse is as follows

```
{
name:"XYZ",
roll:22
}
```

you can't parse this Json with play-json because of the missing field or one way is to define your `Read` and `write` functions which is very cumbersome.

but with fasterXML you can easily parse this Json like :

val a = JsonProvider.fromJsonA

and you can assign `Id` to `case class A` later like `val a1 = a.copy(id="xyz")`

i had this problem then i switched from play-json to fasterXML the problem was
[How to send Json from client with missing fields for its corresponding Case Class after using Json.format function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180849/how-to-send-json-from-client-with-missing-fields-for-its-corresponding-case-clas)

Comment: Hey nice. Thanks. Accepting your answer as it seems appropriate for the question. I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: I have edited my ans to explain the problems with Play's Bulit in JSON.

Comment: You can wrap the case class parameters using Option and then read the json with he missing parameter.